# SQL : Coalesce within where clause giving error Oracle (Not in DB2)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, coalesce

I am trying to use `COALESCE` in WHERE clause, and I am getting the following error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis Failed SQL stmt:

If I remove the `COALESCE`, I don't get the error anymore. I am not sure why would it give me this error as the parenthesis seem correct. Here's my SQL statement:

```
SELECT S.OPRID, A.OPRNAME, S.EMAIL_ADDR
FROM TABLE1 S, TABLE2 A
WHERE COALESCE(S.REHIRE_DT,S.ORIG_HIRE_DT)
        BETWEEN (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM- DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') - 3 DAY)
            AND (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') - 1 DAY)
AND S.EMPLSTATUS = 'A'
AND A.EMPLID     = S.EMPLID
ORDER BY S.OPRID
```

Comment: What's with the "DAY" in the to_date calls?

Comment: Yes LitteBobbyTables, I have put both the expressions in Coalesce function.

Comment: OldProgrammer, we are subtracting 3 day from current date and checking if the dates on the table fall in the last two days.

Comment: Why would the equivalent of this query will work in DB2?
SELECT

S.OPRID ,
A.OPRNAME ,
S.EMAIL_ADDR

FROM
 TABLE1 S ,
 TABLE2 A

WHERE
COALESCE(S.REHIRE_DT,S.ORIG_HIRE_DT) BETWEEN CURRENT DATE - 3 DAY AND CURRENT DATE - 1 DAY

AND S.EMPLSTATUS = 'A'
AND A.EMPLID     = S.EMPLID
ORDER BY S.OPRID

Comment: I've seen this error pop up as a way of telling the user you have too many parentheses, not that you're actually missing one.

Comment: This error is sometimes misleading. Oracle produces this error for different kinds of syntax errors that sometimes have nothing to with parenthesis.

Comment: Can you post your *COALESCE-less* query that works in Oracle?

Comment: The issue was not with the coalesce, it was with the DAY keyword. We were trying to use it in a Oracle specific query( we were migrating from DB2 to Oracle, hence we missed removing the keyword "DAY"). The actual running query has been posted below in the answer by OldProgrammer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the "DAY" word out.  That is not used in oracle in that manner:

```
SELECT S.OPRID, A.OPRNAME, S.EMAIL_ADDR
FROM TABLE1 S, TABLE2 A
WHERE COALESCE(S.REHIRE_DT,S.ORIG_HIRE_DT)
        BETWEEN (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM- DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') - 3 )
            AND (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') - 1 )
AND S.EMPLSTATUS = 'A'
AND A.EMPLID     = S.EMPLID
ORDER BY S.OPRID
```

"DAY" is a keyword to be used as part of the EXTRACT function - see [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm)
The default unit of subtraction from a date field is already in units of days.  I am not familiar with DB2, but I am assuming that your usage of DAY is a DB2-specific attribute.  That is probably not portable SQL.  Yes, oracle's error messages can be confusing at times.

Now that I think about it, you can replace all that "TO_DATE" stuff with just:

```
BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE)-3 AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1
```